# GETH ~ why do i get ERROR: no space left on device

Tags: go-ethereum

While downloading blockchain im getting this error

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: write /root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata/230944.ldb: no space left on device

how this can be resolved? Im downloading it for learning purpose, so i can learn to develop ETH based websites and wallets and mining etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have space left on your machine, your HD is full. Running a full node with ***Geth*** takes space because you have to download the entire blockchain [~50GB]

**Solution 1:** Clean up your machine to get some space

**Solution 2:** Run Geth in light mode `geth --syncmode "light"`. Light clients only download block headers which reduce considerably the chain data folder. [[more info](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Light-client-protocol)]

**Solution 3:** Connect to a third-party hosted node. If you don't want to run your own node locally, you can rely an hosted node such as [INFURA](https://infura.io/)

Comment: if i use this command geth --syncmode "light" then do i need to delete all files under chaindata folder? And start downloading  block chain again?

Comment: Yes you can't combine full sync and light sync. You can remove the chain data folder using `geth removedb`

Comment: My previous command was, which ended up with ERROR : no space left on device

geth --fast --cache 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3


Shall i use this command now to download blockchain with "light"?

Is is correct command to execute?

geth --syncmode "light" --cache 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3

Comment: yeah that looks correct

Comment: thanks greg, one more last stupid question. How much time and disk space new command supposed to use? im super new to this stuff

Comment: Hard to say, it depends of your machine. But according to [this](https://blog.ethereum.org/2018/02/14/geth-1-8-iceberg%C2%B9/) and [that](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7xi4m1/geth_v180_iceberg_go_and_sync_mainnet_within_a/) the latest version of geth (1.8) has incredible improvements in term of sync time. People are talking about a couple of minutes ...

Comment: Alright greg, i have set the command with supervisor, So it will keep on downloading in the background and supervisor will restart geth if somehow it goes down... But another question since its being downloading in background in the ubuntu then how will i come to know that blockchain is fully downloaded? Where i will enter eth.syncing command? in normal putty after geth console?

Comment: one more thing i just notice, While running with --syncmode "light" no .ldb files are created, there is a file 000001.log and its size keep on increasing... Is it expected behavior?

Comment: to know when you are fully sync, you can run periodically `geth console` and execute `eth.syncing` and compare currentBlock to highestBlock (something like  `percentage_sync = (currentBlock-highestBlock)*100 if percentage_sync < 99 => RAISE ALERT`). About ldb file, I don't know in depth how it is implemented in geth!

Comment: its running so slow with new command :-( only 1 .ldb file is downloaded till now :-( did i miss something in my command?     geth --syncmode "light" --cache 1024 --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3

Comment: `--cache 1024` might be too much for your machine. default is 128

Comment: So shall i remove --cache 1024 and run again?

Comment: i removed --cache 1024 i hope it should work a bit faster now

Comment: still its very slow :-( not sure what could be the reason :-( new command is.......  geth --syncmode "light" --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3

Comment: i have $5 digitalocean droplet just for learning all this crypto stuff... its really very irritating takes ages and gives nothing as output ;-(

Comment: @shawn it will take you about 2 weeks to download full blockchain, so, lower your expectations

Comment: @Nulik yes if it takes 2 week or more then i really have no problem. But i want be sure things are going correctly. But now it looks like it has stopped downloading.. In this line does it mean, Currently block 5112188 is being process? ... INFO [02-18|10:49:17] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=7.658ms   number=5112188 hash=7b808eâ€¦11ed0e ignored=0

Comment: Shouldn't take 2 weeks to sync in light mode but however it looks like you are sync now, the last block no is 5112194 [[see here](https://etherscan.io/)]. I don't know why exactly is was so long. Might be interesting to share the details of your VM.

Comment: i see this line INFO [02-18|11:18:20] Imported new block headers               count=1   elapsed=8.896ms   number=5112296 hash=e83444â€¦6c1fae ignored=0
with block number - 5112296 and current block height is also 5112296 in etherscan.io does it mean its completed downloading blockchain?

Comment: looks like blockchain is download correctly and completely... > eth.blockNumber
5112330

Comment: I guess so but bear in mind that Ethereum network mined a new block every 10 sec so you have to keep it running to stay up to date. Congrats for this first step in the blockchain world. Keep in mind that is a Peer2p network with several implementations of client software. If you're not satisfied with Geth, you can still switch to another one ( [parity](https://www.parity.io/) is the second most famous and the [full list is here](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/choosing-a-client.html) )

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73351/discussion-on-answer-by-greg-jeanmart-geth-why-do-i-get-error-no-space-left-o).